# Session variables in node express-session don't persist to the next request

Tags: node.js, session

I am using a basic node express-session setup with memory store and I have this code on the server:

```
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));

app.post('/api/logIn', function(req, res) {
    req.session.userName = req.body.userName;
}

app.get('/api/getProfile', function(req, res) { 
    User.findOne({'userName' : req.session.userName}, 
        function (err, userProfile) {
        console.log('getProfile executed for user:' + req.session.userName);
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(userProfile);
    });
});
```

The problem is that *req.session.userName* from getProfile route is undefined, although it is not in the previous request to logIn route. I inspected HTTP headers and strangely there are no headers dealing with cookies, from the server or from the client. Right now I have no idea what could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say `cookie: { secure: true }`, but is your web server actually on a secure connection? If not, then the cookie won't be written.

From the [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options):

> Please note that secure: true is a recommended option. However, it
>   requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure
>   cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the
>   cookie will not be set.

Comment: The server wasn't using https, so there goes one mistake. But when I changed the option to false, the same problem still occurs :(.

Comment: Are you using `body-parser`?

Comment: Yes, these are all middle-ware I am currently using: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(require('express-session')({...

Comment: Yes, I checked the values from POST route and they are O.K.

Comment: Try sending some response in your routes after you set the session var.

Comment: Thanks Patosai, this was the last missing link. The server actually was returning NOTHING, not before I forced it with res.end(). Now sessions work as normal. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Also its important to note if you are using `fetch()` to make your API calls to include `{ credentials: 'include' }` in the options of your `fetch()` call. Otherwise the cookie will not set properly and your session will not persist. Make sure that on your server side you do something like:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

so that your headers are set properly and cors wont be an issue. Took me awhile to figure this out but its working now!

Answer (score 0):

The session need is stored in a cookie, so we use this to parse it, some like this:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// must use cookieParser before expressSession
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Full example: http://code.runnable.com/U0tEnHwraXYyp-JG/simple-usage-of-express-session-and-cookie-parser-with-express-for-node-js

Comment: [No longer needed](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options) for recent versions of `express-session`.